# How to animate a simple movement UIKit

Tags: swift, animation

I am trying to animate a UIImageView so that it moves down on the screen, but I can't figure out how to code it or organize as I am somewhat new to Swift.
I use an ImageView called mrock. . All I want to do is move it down in a straight line.

Would I use something like

```
blank.moveToPoint
```

and then the coordinates but I don't really know.

Comment: So find out. A UIImageView is a UIView. So look in the UIView documentation. Do you see anything called "animate..."? Or how about googling? Or even searching Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 1):

As Greg says in his answer, the UIView methods who's names start with animateWithDuration are a good start.

If you're using autoLayout, however, then animating a view's center or frame property often doesn't operate as expected, since the constraints can take over and move your views back to their layout-based positions.

With Auto-layout, instead what you should do is create one or more position constraints on your view in IB, then control-drag from those constraints into your view controller to create outlets.

Then you change the constraint's constant setting and call layoutIfNeeded inside your animation block.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UIView.animateWithDuration` it's override multiple times and it can take more parameters, but the simple one is:

```
    UIView.animateWithDuration(5.0) {
        self.blank.center = CGPoint(x: 280, y: 450)
    }
```